# Testing Windows phone 7 Application

Tags: windows-phone

Forgive me for what may seem as a stupid question but, after some rummaging around on the web, I can't seem to find how to test my Windows Phone Application. I'm not referring to the guidelines, I'm actually referring to sending it to Microsoft for them to check if it's "okay" or checking it on Visual Studio as I think there is a way of doing that in VS.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough) should help. Keep in mind that before you send it to microsoft (or appHub) your app needs to be fairly perfect. Submissions aren't free :)

edit: this is assuming you were asking how to submit it for review. When you submit your app, the review process starts.

Answer (score 1):

For app testing you need the [sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)...  With the sdk you have a perfect emulator for test your apps. For app deploy on your device, after you've bougth the annual subscription to be a developer, you have to associate your phone and install zune on your pc (read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)).
After you tests you can submit your app through this process (read [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough)).